# How to deploy a ML model as a local iot edge module

Tags: azure-iot-edge, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a machine learning model registered in the model registry of my Azure Machine Learning workspace.

Now I want to containerize such model inside a **Linux docker image** exposing a rest api; then, I have to deploy it as an IoT Edge module to an edge PC, where other modules will invoke it locally and receive predictions.

I have searched in Microsoft documentation, but I haven't found a solution to my problem, since the suggested examples and tutorials talk about deploying entire iot edge solutions or using azure ml cli to deploy models, instead I have to add this module to an existing deployment manifest where other modules are already present.

Comment: Did you look at the doc already? [Create and deploy custom IoT Edge modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-machine-learning-edge-06-custom-modules?view=iotedge-2020-11)

Answer (score 0):

The way IoT Edge works is that it uses Routes to manage communication between modules, IoT Hub, and any leaf devices. The $edgeHub module twin contains a desired property called routes that declares how messages are passed within a deployment.

> I have to add this module to an existing deployment manifest where other modules are already present.

What you need to do is to edit the Deployment manifest ([see an example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition?view=iotedge-2020-11#deployment-manifest-example)) and add your module inside $edgeAgent.properties.desired.modules + define your routes in $edgeHub.properties.desired.routes . This can also be done in the Azure Portal UI.

> other modules will invoke it locally and receive predictions.

Since your implementation is using a Rest Api your route would just need to guarantee that, before you send the data `INTO $upstream`, it is sent to your new ML module, something like: `INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/YOURMLMODEL/inputs/input1\")"`

You can learn more about [how to deploy modules and establish routes in IoT Edge here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition?view=iotedge-2020-11).